# BLE GATT - what is easiest way to see the 'schemas'?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Am I the only missing the viewer info to see all attributes in GATT and GAP? A simple and quick lookup of for instance this one (doesn't work anymore) seems to indicate it is easy to find the required info (in my case the UUID's and descriptors):
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.cycling_power_feature.xml

I have clicked on quite some menus and I am sure I just overlook something. But I just cannot believe the BT organization makes a website with so little links to the actual info.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be any links from the site, but it does look like you can look at the document directly:

https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.cycling_power_feature.xml

Comment: So I arrive at BT’s site. How do I navigate there?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The only workaround I hve found to view the XML file is to modify the URL with the required characteristic. You can get the characteristic name from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/ .  It might be worth reporting the broken link to the BT SIG website. https://bluetooth.service-now.com/ess/submit_case.do

Comment: Ah!! Great. Cannot upvote you (not enough rights yet). But compliments for the answer